# Should we delete one of these tags: 'legal-terms' or 'terminology?

Tags: discussion, tags

Need we both?

[legal-terms](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-terms) vs [terminology](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)

Comment: If the community expresses a preference one of the two can be merged into the other and a synonym can be created.

Answer (score 1):

**Term**inology encompasses Legal **Terms**... Does it not?

I find it odd though because a lot of the questions with either of these tags probably shouldn't have the tag (like this [one](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7012/is-it-legal-to-display-images-found-using-public-apis-on-my-website)). So we'd probably have to go through the questions before a moderator performs a merge :)

Answer (score 1):

We probably just want to watch out for potential confusion between legal and contract "Terms."  Favoring "Terminology" might help with that problem.