# should the "legal-terms" and "terminology" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

It seems to me that there is no systemic distinction being made between the [legal-terms](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-terms) and [terminology](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tags, and one might usefully be made a synonym of the other. A new "contract-terms" tag might plausibly be created for those questions which are about specific terms in a contract, and not about legal terminology in general.

This was briefly discussed some 5 years ago in [Should we delete one of these tags: 'legal-terms' or 'terminology?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/426/should-we-delete-one-of-these-tags-legal-terms-or-terminology) but there was little comment and no decision. We now have much mnorem data on how the tags have been used.

Comment: The tags have been merged. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Good suggestion. Fully implemented.